# Grouping and Managing node.js Middleware

Tags: node.js, express, middleware, node.js-connect

If I've made some middleware that works together, what's the best convention for grouping and managing the functionality?

In my `server.js` file, I've currently just got them listed one after another with `app.use` calls.

It's occurred to me however that if the first one in my set doesn't produce any data, the subsequent ones in the group are fine to skip.  I guess this is ultimately an aggregation although I haven't seen any examples of such in other projects.

Answer (score 1):

The [connect](http://www.senchalabs.org/connect/) middleware has a good example for this kind of problem. Take a look at the [bodyParser](http://www.senchalabs.org/connect/bodyParser.html):

```
app.use(connect.bodyParser());  // use your own grouping here
```

is equivalent to

```
app.use(connect.json());
app.use(connect.urlencoded());
app.use(connect.multipart());
```

Internally the `bodyParser` function just passes the `req` and `res` objects through each of the before mentioned middleware functions

```
exports = module.exports = function bodyParser(options){
  var _urlencoded = urlencoded(options)
    , _multipart = multipart(options)
    , _json = json(options);

  return function bodyParser(req, res, next) {
    _json(req, res, function(err){
      if (err) return next(err);
      _urlencoded(req, res, function(err){
        if (err) return next(err);
        _multipart(req, res, next);
      });
    });
  }  
};
```

The full code can be found at the github [repo](https://github.com/senchalabs/connect/blob/master/lib/middleware/bodyParser.js)

Answer (score 0):

***edit***

Informed in the comments bellow that passing an array will acieve the exact same thing, so no need for an additional module. :-)

---

I was looking for a way to do this too as my application is very granular, but I didn't want to nest everything as in the other answer.

I'm sure there is something more comprehensive out there already, but I did this in the end:

```
 /**
 * Macro method to group together middleware.
 */
function macro (...middlewares) {
    // list of middlewares is passed in and a new one is returned
    return (req, res, next) => {
        // express objects are locked in this scope and then
        // _innerMacro calls itself with access to them
        let index = 0;
        (function _innerMacro() {
            // methods are called in order and passes itself in as next
            if(index < middlewares.length){
                middlewares[index++](req, res, _innerMacro)
            } else {

                // finally, next is called
                next();
            }
        })();
    }
}
```

And then use it like this:

```
var macro = macro(
    middleware1,
    middleware2,
    middleware3
);

app.post('/rout', macro);
```

Comment: Or just `app.post('/rout', middleware1, middleware2, middleware3)`, or `let mw = [ middleware1, middleware2, middleware3 ]; app.post('/rout', mw)` (for easier reuse)

Comment: The fist example is exactly what i was trying to avoid as i ended up with a lot of duplication that way, but i didnt know you could use arrays. Very nice, thank you.

Comment: Now i know why there was nothing out there to do it, was inbuilt the whole time! :-)

Comment: The original question is pretty old, so perhaps at the time it wasn't yet possible to pass arrays-of-middleware :D